# Hg Clone Remote Repository over VPN

Tags: mercurial, clone, vpn

I am trying to clone a remote repository over VPN connection. It takes forever to clone. Our remote repository exposed as http endpoint. Using Tortoise Hg clone takes forever to complete. Here is the hg command appeared while cloning in tortoise hg.

```
hg clone --verbose -- httpurlofremoterepository
```

Size of the repository is less than 3 GB. Using CISCO VPN Any Connect client. Can I make this clone faster?

Comment: 1. How is the remote repository exposed - using hgweb script or in some other way? 2. Do you have disk access to the repository (i.e. can you copy its parts as files)? 3. What speed does your VPN connection allow when simply transmitting stream of data (e.g. a large file)? I mean that the bottleneck can be in VPN and not in Mercurial.

Comment: @Inspired  I think I need some time to find these answers.

Comment: Looks like the problem with VPN connection. It is too slow to copy files from share folder into local box. Trying to identify cause of it.